# Can we construct unbounded categories?

Tags: logic, set-theory

If we treat $Set$ as a $0$-category, then $1$-category is universal class (the proper class which contains all the sets), $2$-category is the collection which contains all the classes. And so on... And I have three questions:

1. By this way, can we construct infinitely many categories that for each defined category, we always can construct a higher-level category which contains all the object of all the preceding level (such as the preceding level of universal class is $Set$) (i.e.there is no greatest collection containing all categories)?
2. Can we extend this construction to $α$-category("$α$" is an arbitrary ordinal number)? If not, why?
3. Can someone recommend any book that talks about my question explicitly?

Comment: What you are calling "categories" have in fact not much to do with [category theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory).

Comment: I am sorry.Besides,can you answer my 3 questions?

Comment: No, I have no idea what the answer is.

Answer (score 3):

In light of this question, your other question that I just answered makes a lot more sense.

- (1. & 2.) Yes, we can. Under the mild assumption that there is a proper class of Grothendieck universes, the following holds: Take any set $x$. Then there is a Grothendieck universe $U_{0}$ such that $x \in U_{0}$. We may now form a class sized category $C_{0}$ inside $U_{0}$. (The reason we want to be able to put $x$ in $U_{0}$ is that in typical applications we want to construct $C_{0}$ from $x$ or at least have that $x$ is an object of $C_{0}$.) In particular, taking $x = U_{0}$, there is a Grothendieck universe $U_{1}$ such that $U_{0} \in U_{1}$. Now, in $U_{1}$, $C_{0}$ is a small category and we may use it to construct another class sized category $C_{1}$ in $U_{1}$. This process can be continued set many times and - under slightly stronger assumptions - even 'class many times', but the latter rarely seems to be of interest.
- (3.) Sure. I suggest that you take a look at [Shulman's Set theory for category theory](http://arxiv.org/abs/0810.1279). It is written by a non-set-theorist and hence readable without too much knowledge about the set theoretical details. Unfortunately, it contains some mistakes. Two of them are that the author assumes that every model of $\operatorname{ZFC}$ is well-founded and hence isomorphic to a transitive one via the Mostowksi collapse. This isn't true, but no harm in done by just considering well-founded models in this setting. Another mistake (which is related to the first one) is that the author claims the existence of a model of $\operatorname{ZFC}$ implies the existence of a transitive model of $\operatorname{ZFC}$. This is provably false, but again, you may just assume that transitive models exist in our background universe. Other than that he does a nice job at explaining some set-theoretical foundations of category theory in a manner that should be accessible to people who haven't studied axiomatic foundations like $\operatorname{ZFC}$ before.

Comment: :I am appreciate a lot of your help.As this question confused me a long time and I can't find a appropriate answer that can exactly answer my question.Maybe because English is not my first language plus I am just a begginner who are interested in Set theory.                           Besides,is the word "set" means a broaden way than in ZFC models?For example,the proper class defined in ZFC cannot be a set.However,in Grothendieck Set Theory,proper class defined in ZFC can be a set as there is another universe contains that.Am I right?

Comment: You are right The confusion arises because a class in one model of $\operatorname{ZFC}$ can be (and in the above situation always is) a set in a larger model of $\operatorname{ZFC}$. For example, let $U$ be a Grothendieck universe. By definition that implies that $U$ is a set. But $U$ actually models that it (i.e. the universe $U$) is a proper class. More precisely, inside $U$ we can define $V^U = \{ x \mid U \models x = x \}$ and $U \models V^U \text{ is a proper class}$. However, in our background universe we see that $V^U = U$ is really a set.

Comment: Regarding your other question: There is a more than one sensible way to construct such infinite order languages and they're actively studied. However it's not clear which of them you are looking for in your question.

Comment: :Briefly,my other question is if a level of Grothendieck universe Uα is a member of one level higher universe U(α+1),then all the subsets of Uα(including itself) is in U(α+1)?In addition,each "category" I defined above is a Grothendieck universe?

Comment: Yes, every subset of $U(\alpha)$ is a member of $U(\alpha+1)$. The second question: Well, this depends on where (i.e. in which model) you define your category $\operatorname{Set}$. If you have a proper class $(U_{\alpha} \mid \alpha \in \operatorname{Ord})$ of Grothendieck universes and define your categories in precisely those $U_{\alpha}$, then the answer is yes - you end up with the exact same sequence.

Comment: :thank you very much for your patient

Comment: You're very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: look into [Grothendieck set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%E2%80%93Grothendieck_set_theory).

Comment: I have had a look.But I am not sure that answered my question in a positive way

Comment: So what more do you want?

Comment: Is this exactly the Grothendieck universe?Furthermore,all the categories is a member of Grothendieck universe?

Comment: The theory provides  a hierarchy of (Grothendieck) universes. The universes are just like the "categories" that you wish for.

Comment: And my question is there unbound (Grothendieck) universes?I haven't seen on Wikipedia talked about my question 1 and 2.That is what I am looking for

Comment: The universes within Grothendieck set theory provide precisely what you are asking for.

Comment: I don't know what is the meaning of the word "set" which mentioned in Grothendieck set theory.Maybe it is different with the "set" in ZF.So all the "categories" i mentioned above are sets.In addition,each of those is included in a (Grothendieck) universes.Therefore it implies my question positively??

Comment: Grothendieck set theory is a strengthening of ZF set theory with a broader notion of set. As far as I can see it provides an affirmative answer to your question. If you want a textbook account og Grothenbieck set theory, see the introductory chapters of Cohn's *Universal Algebra".